# All array images are not accessed by JS function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array of images,so that user can click on arrow to change images,but only first three images of the array index are accessed and not rest.
here is my code snippet.

```
 <html>
 <body>
<div id="debug"></div>
<div id="rightDisplay">
<div id="imgread"></div>
<img id="currentImg" alt="RoboustImage" src="http://i.imgur.com/dCS4tQk.jpg" title="click to view full scape" height="50%" width="50%" style="margin-left:20%;" />
<img id="changeImg" alt="clickandchange" src="1461670638_hand-right.png" onclick="changeImage()"></div>

</table>


<script>
var theSource;
var array;
var curImage;

function showImage(imgName) {
    var curImage = document.getElementById('currentImg');
    var thePath = 'http://i.imgur.com/';
    var theSource = thePath + imgName;
    curImage.src = theSource;
    // curImage.alt = imgName;

    // curImage.title = imgName;
}

function changeImage(dir) {
    var img = document.getElementById('currentImg');

    var imgs = ["http://i.imgur.com/dCS4tQk.jpg", "http://i.imgur.com/JKNnuSE.jpg", "http://i.imgur.com/9wHVhck.jpg", "http://i.imgur.com/dCS4tQk.jpg", "http://i.imgur.com/ZqoEU9o.jpg", "http://i.imgur.com/SpBfUZi.jpg", "http://i.imgur.com/JKNnuSE.jpg", "http://i.imgur.com/YwAmPYu.jpg", "http://i.imgur.com/T7NBjJm.jpg", "http://i.imgur.com/ujJ3g1k.jpg"];
    img.src = imgs[imgs.indexOf(img.src) + (dir || 1)] || imgs[dir ? imgs.length - 1 : 0];
    // var debug = document.getElementById('imgread').innerHTML=img.src;

}

</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean not accessed? What precisely is happening when you debug?

Comment: You have duplicate images in your array. `indexOf` finds the first index. Once the 4th image is selected, it also returns 0, because those URLs are the same.

Comment: oh..after removing  duplicate URL it that works..but why this causes an issues due to same url, won't index of them will be treated differently ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code does not support duplicate images in your `imgs` url. `Array.indexOf` returns the first index at which an element appears. Since the URL at index `3` also appears at index `0`, it will never get any further.

I'd keep track of the index in a javascript variable to circumvent this issue. Here's an example:

```js
var getNextImageUrl = (function() {

  var currentIndex = 0;
  var imgs = ["a", "b", "c"];

  return function(direction) {

    var dir = direction || 1; // Default direction is forward

    var newIndex = currentIndex + dir;

    // Loop when end is reached
    if (newIndex >= imgs.length) {
      newIndex = 0;
    } else if (newIndex < 0) {
      newIndex = imgs.length - 1;
    }

    currentIndex = newIndex;

    return imgs[currentIndex];

  };

}())
```

Comment: If you don't like the "long" loop logic, you could use `var newIndex = currentIndex + dir >= 0 ? (currentIndex + dir) % imgs.length : imgs.length - 1;`. But my advice is to keep it simple and readable.